# Special Price with Configurable Products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, magento-2.1, special-price

We have been converted some Configurable products from Downloadable products. But have an issue in there, we can't be set Special Price(link open the modal set Advancing Pricing is hidden), and very strange, Magento is automatically set Special Price for them.

**E.g**: A product has a price is $200, it's automatically set to $150 when converting to Configurable Products. We will see it in the frontend or via the `get final price()` function. Before, we had config a special price for the old downloadable product.

**My Question:**

> How to Magento ignore set Special Price or we will control the special
> price for the configurable product?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*We are using the Magento version 2.1.1*

Comment: What's method being used? Admin Edit or Import/Export?

Comment: Hi @Anki
E.g: 
` /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
 $product->load(1);
echo $product->getFinalProduct(); //return 150
`

Comment: @Bill, Also I face the same problem, how I can make set special price link being visible, did you get it ?

Answer (score 0):

The special price just as the regular price for the configurable product is set in its assigned sample products.